# Flow complaining about method calls on an object within an Object.values callback

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Here is my code (also viewable on [flow.org/try](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBjGBDAzrsABQFMAnXOAOzAG9UwxLsBbYgLjFwBdSBLSgOb0wwjFW6kArhi5xSACiasAlLWEMuAC164AdEuJgAvIxbFhAX3QNc2AJ4AJXvNV0GDMZQoxiu+APkAAycAGjAASQByZjAAEhotHX0zC0DlS1QrTHEuMAAHYjg8n2M1BgArOE1KDkpiJBJyKnlIgCkq6gBlZl4tSOUQ4XLsDABrWvqiMgpKFtaR0bAAGUKmUgATfsz0AHkAI3LiGV0AN2wYSWJceQKin2VdKDkAURHNG+mqYwA+MvzPyi6WyOZzpCzKIA)):

```
/**
 * @flow
 */

class Person {
  name: string

  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name
  }

  sayHi() {
    console.log(`Hi, I'm ${this.name}`)
  }
}

const people = {
  john: new Person('John Smith'),
  jack: new Person('Jack Leonard')
}

Object.values(people).forEach(person => {
  person.sayHi() // this line causes an issue with flow
})
```

It does not like the fact that I'm using `person.sayHi()`. I get this error:

```
21:   person.sayHi()      
      ^ call of method `sayHi`. Method cannot be called on
21:   person.sayHi()
      ^ mixed
```

It seems that `Object.values` returns a type of `Array<mixed>`. I've tried to do a refinement on the type like so:

```
Object.values(people).forEach(person => {
  if (typeof person === 'object' && person != null) {
    person.sayHi()
  }
})
```

However, that still gives an error:

```
22:     person.sayHi()        
        ^ call of method `sayHi`. Function cannot be called on
[LIB] static/v0.49.1/flowlib/core.js:52:     static values(object: any): Array<mixed>;
                                                                               ^ mixed
```

Any tips on getting this to work would be appreciated.

Comment: try `(Object.values(people): Array<Person>).forEach(person => { person.sayHi() })`

Comment: hmm, flow [doesn't seem to like](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBjGBDAzrsABQFMAnXOAOzAG9UwxLsBbYgLjFwBdSBLSgOb0wwjFW6kArhi5xSACiasAlLWEMuAC164AdEuJgAvIxbFhAX3QNc2AJ4AJXvNV0GDMZQoxiu+APkAAycAGjAASQByZjAAEhotHX0zC0DlS1QrTHEuMAAHYjg8n2M1BgArOE1KDkpiJBJyKnlIgCkq6gBlZl4tSOUQ4XLsDABrWvqiMgpKFtaR0bAAGUKmUgATfsz0eQB5ACNy4hldADdsGEliXHkCop9lDgBBUlJ7AB5GmYA+ZV0oOQAURGmlu0yoxm+tHy4Moulsjmcqgs6VQQA) that typecast.

Answer (score 0):

> hmm, flow doesn't seem to like that typecast

yea, this was just a quick guess. flow ain't my strong suit.

The "problem" is [this declaration](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/master/lib/core.js#L52). I don't know wether you can somehow overwrite this declaration in flow. I'm not even sure this would be a good idea for something as generic as `Object.values()`.

I'd wish there was something like the type casting I tried; as it is possible in Typescript. Something like: I know better than you what we're dealing with, so cast this to ... 
But I didn't find anything in the docs.

Meanwhile you can use this:

```
function typedValues<T>(object: {[key:string]: T}): Array<T> {
    return Object.keys(object).map(key => object[key]);
}

typedValues(people).forEach((person:Person) => {
    person.sayHi();
})
```

typing `person` is not mandatory, but it provides a better Error message if the Array contains foreign types.

Comment: Casts in Flow are safe. If you want to do an unsafe cast you have to cast through `any` (an unsafe type) e.g. `((foo: any): TypeIWant)`. This will tell Flow to just trust you.